# adding child node under every parent node in for loop in treeview in tkinter

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I am trying to make a treeview which displays data from a mysql database. It retrieves the data, and converts it into a list of tuples. I have already created a for loop which quite nicely takes the data and puts it into a treeview.

```
count = 0
for record in rows: #forloop adding all the information from data list, no matter how many their are in the list
        my_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=count, text='', values=(record[0], record[1], record[2], record[3], record[4], record[5]))

                        
    count += 1
```

However, under every parent node, I want the for loop to also place a child node. The current treeview looks like this

```
    studentid firstname   lastname  class1  class2  class3
0           5    Ayoung        ere      23      29      22
1           6      Emma       4343      24      22      25
2           7      John     343G&$      28      26      27
3           8   Anthony        @^b      26      25      22
4           9   Enshean        E(!      23      26      29
5          12       Ian    %^&67HN      23      25      26
6          13    Ludwig  Beethoven      23      26      29
7          14  Wolfgang     Mozart      23      24      26
8          19    Joseph      Haydn      23      26      27
9          20   Enshean        @&V      23      26      29
10         21   Enshean        L^&      23      26      29
```

Under every person in the list there will be a child node that would display 3 pieces of information from another list that was retrieved from a database. The list looks like this:

```
[(22, 'Math', 'Mr. Rosario', 'D2'), (23, 'Music', 'Mr. Young', 'M1'), (24, 'Biology', 'Ms. Marks', 'C4'), (25, 'Chemistry', 'Mr. Musk', 'C2'), (26, 'Physics', 'Mr. Walrath', 'A8'), (27, 'Economics', 'Mr. Sinclair', 'E12'), (28, 'DGT', 'Mr. Turing', 'F3'), (29, 'English', 'Mr. Gibson', 'B5')]
```

As we can see in my treeview, under class1,2 and 3 there is a number, that corresponds to a id from another database as seen above. What I want in the child node is under every one of the classes, will be the name of the class. For example:

```
    studentid firstname   lastname  class1  class2  class3
0           5    Ayoung        ere      23      29      22
>                                      Music  English Math   
1           6      Emma       BI$!      24      22      25
>                                     Biology  Math Chemistry
```

It's kind of hard to put it into words, but hopefully you get the idea. Any help in trying to put a child node with the corresponding data under every parent node in a for loop would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn your list in a dictonary: {number: subject}.
If your list is called `rows2` you can do

```
dic = {values[0]: values[1] for values in rows2}
```

Then add the subitem in the tree with

```
tree.insert(count, 'end', values=('',)*3 + tuple(dic[record[i]] for i in range(3,6)))
```

where `count` is the item iid and `record` the values from the first database.

Full example

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
columns = ['studentid', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'class1', 'class2', 'class3']
tree = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=columns)
for col in columns:
    tree.heading(col, text=col)
tree.pack()

# first database
rows = [
    [5, 'Ayoung', 'ere', 23, 29, 22],
    [6, 'Emma', '4343', 24, 22, 25],
    [7, 'John', '343G&$', 28, 26, 27],
    [8, 'Anthony', '@^b', 26, 25, 22],
    [9, 'Enshean', 'E(!', 23, 26, 29],
    [12, 'Ian', '%^&67HN', 23, 25, 26],
    [13, 'Ludwig', 'Beethoven', 23, 26, 29],
    [14, 'Wolfgang', 'Mozart', 23, 24, 26],
    [19, 'Joseph', 'Haydn', 23, 26, 27],
    [20, 'Enshean', '@&V', 23, 26, 29],
    [21, 'Enshean', 'L^&', 23, 26, 29]
]
# second database
rows2 = [
    (22, 'Math', 'Mr. Rosario', 'D2'), (23, 'Music', 'Mr. Young', 'M1'),
    (24, 'Biology', 'Ms. Marks', 'C4'), (25, 'Chemistry', 'Mr. Musk', 'C2'),
    (26, 'Physics', 'Mr. Walrath', 'A8'),
    (27, 'Economics', 'Mr. Sinclair', 'E12'), (28, 'DGT', 'Mr. Turing', 'F3'),
    (29, 'English', 'Mr. Gibson', 'B5')
]
# dictionary from second database
dic = {values[0]: values[1] for values in rows2}

# put data in treeview
for count, record in enumerate(rows): #forloop adding all the information from data list, no matter how many their are in the list
    tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=count, text='', values=(record[0], record[1], record[2], record[3], record[4], record[5])) # data from first database
    tree.insert(count, 'end', values=('',)*3 + tuple(dic[record[i]] for i in range(3,6)))  # subitem using second database

root.mainloop()
```